# RewriteRule Detecting numbers greater than 9

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to detect numbers in a URL greater than 9 at the end of my URL. For example:

"...com/celtic-jewelry/traditional/10"

I've a work around in my .htaccess using two seperate lines that work as a combination (the 1st line detecting number less than 10, the 2nd detecting numbers over 9, but I'm wondering what the correct method is? My .htaccess is below, thanks!

RewriteRule ^celtic-jewelry/([a-z-'/]+)/([0-9])$ /product.php?flags=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^celtic-jewelry/([a-z-'/]+)/(.[0-9])$ /product.php?flags=$1&page=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

How about just the following single rule, to replace your two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^celtic-jewelry/([a-z'/-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /product.php?flags=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Here `[0-9]+` means "one or more digits 0-9".  So that catches all numbers of 1, 2, or more digits, in just one rule.  Although the title of your question is about numbers greater than 9, the context makes it clear that you're trying to capture all numbers, whether 1, 2, or more digits.

Also, note that in `[a-z'/-]+`, I moved the second `-` to the end of the brackets.  You wrote it as `[a-z-'/]+`, but the problem there is that the second `-` could act as a range operator, while I think your intent was to use it as a literal dash character.  To keep the `-` from acting as a range operator, you have to either put it first or last within the brackets, or else escape it with a backslash (`\-`).

Comment: Would work for two digits right? But I need it to work for any number of digits.

Comment: Edited to make this more clear.  It works for any number of digits.

Comment: Be aware that this would catch ```/00```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right:

```
RewriteRule ^celtic-jewelry/([a-z-'/]+)/([1-9][0-9]+)$ product.php?flags=$1&page=$2 [L]
```